# How to load local text file into string variable in ReactNative Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my ReactNative project there are some static text files which i'd like to load into a string variable. Like this way:

```
var content = loadPlainTextFile("resources/tags.txt");
var tags = content.split("\n");
```

I tried require in the same way i'm requiring javascript files, but it doesn't work because react native gives exception "Unable to resolve module ./data/tags.txt".

```
var customData = require('./data/tags.txt');
```

I guess that require() is not able to handle plain text files?

How to do correctly?

Comment: show us example of content of `tags.txt` file

Comment: its a plain list of words, line by line

Comment: Your question is legitime. Why is it so easy to require JS files, JSON files, even binary files (images), but not a simple text file. Of course we export any string with
`export default "some useful text"`
but we are loosing the type, and syntax highlighting, which is a shame.
Example of some useful extensions:
`config.yml`
`query.grapql`
`shader.glsl`

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Create a constants.js like below, where you are exporting the constants.

```
module.exports = {
  SPRING_CONFIG: {tension: 40, friction: 3},
  COLOR: {
    COLOR1: '#ffffff',
    COLOR2: '#eeeeee',
    BLACK_TEXT: '#333',
  },
};
```

Then in whatever file you are trying to import it, import it as...

```
import CONSTANTS from './constants'; //Make sure you put the right folder path.
console.log(CONSTANTS.COLOR.BLACK_TEXT);
```

Comment: i meant a plain text file containing words i want to handle in my app as an array of strings, like var words = loadFIle("resources/tags.txt").split("\n");

Comment: You can do the same thing with the .js file too... something like.. tags:{json like object} - Will it not solve your purpose? Is there any special condition that it needs to be a .txt file?

Comment: i found that multiline strings are possible now when encapsulated in ticks. thats what i needed here. so yes, your approach is a solution

Comment: This is now confusing though, as this is one of the search results and it's answered, but the answer is not for importing a text file into a string(for which there are plenty of valid use cases)

Comment: another answer for a question half read.

Answer (score 17):

The question is specifically asking about how to import a text file using something like:

`import textFile from './textFile.txt'`

This is possible using [React-Native-Local-Resource](https://github.com/IgorBelyayev/React-Native-Local-Resource). The library allows you to asynchronously load any type of text file.