# Loading a file as string with React Native packager

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible with React Native Packager to load a text file as a string? As the same as Webpack's [Raw Loader](https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader).

Example:

```
const someString = require('./something.txt');
console.log(someString);
```

What is the closest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use the [React Native FS module](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) which gives you FS-like commands within your React code:

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs')
RNFS.readFile('./something.txt', 'utf8')
    .then((contents) => {
      console.warn(contents)
    })
```

Comment: How can RNFS access a file included by React Native packager?  Is not the package some kind of compressed file?

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution:

https://github.com/callstack-io/haul

> Haul is a drop-in replacement for react-native CLI built on open tools like Webpack. It can act as a development server or bundle your React Native app for production.

Answer (score 3):

There is a library for exactly this problem: [React-Native-Local-Resource](https://github.com/IgorBelyayev/React-Native-Local-Resource). The library allows you to asynchronously load any type of text file in the way that you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to load local text file into string variable in ReactNative Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517202/how-to-load-local-text-file-into-string-variable-in-reactnative-project)

While you can't require a text file with React Native, you can require a JSON file. If it's possible to switch to JSON, you'll be set.