# Packing js file to be inserted into React Native's WebView

Tags: react-native

I am creating a webview in a react native script, such as

```
<WebView source="https://www.google.com" />
```

However, I would like to inject a whole bunch of javascripts into the webview. The scripts to be included is located at let's say additionalScripts.js (which may import a whole bunch of dependencies such as jquery etc.

So intuitive I am trying to do

```
import additionalScripts from './additionalScripts.js'

<WebView source="https://www.google.com" injectedJavaScript={additionalScripts} />
```

Firstly it does not work.

Secondly, how do it make sure that the additionalScripts imported has been properly 'webpacked' and 'uglified' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `injectedJavaScript` needs a string, but the `import` actually executes the JS file and exports the result as an object.

To load the file as text, you can try something like [React Native FS module](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs), I learned about it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37657621/146656).

```js
// ...
import RNFS from require('react-native-fs');
// ...
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      additionalScripts: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    RNFS.readFile('./additionalScripts.js', 'utf8')
      .then((contents) => {
        this.setState({
          additionalScripts: contents
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
      if(!this.state.additionalScripts) {
        return null;
      }

      return <WebView 
        source="https://www.google.com"
        injectedJavaScript={additionalScripts} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It does not really solve my problem though. In the end, I use webpack to pack my js file first, before injecting them into webview.

Comment: @hermitian can you please share your webpack answer how you done using webpack. i am in the same problem and don't know how to solve using webpack